# Formatting manually numbered list in MS-Office

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, formatting

Trying to format crossword clues in Microsoft Word. Clue numbers are manually formatted, as clues are not strictly a numbered list (not all numbers appear).

1. Would like numbers right aligned
2. Would like clues left aligned
3. Multiple lined clues should be formatted like an actual bulleted or numbered list (so the text is aligned with text, not aligned with number)

See example image of crossword clues properly formatted:

[image: example image]

So far, I have not been able to do this.

Comment: Set a decimal tab for the numbers, and a left tab for the clue text.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using a table.

Make a table with three columns: the first one top and right aligned, the second empty, the third left aligned. Adjust the width (and font size if needed) of the second one until it takes up the space you want between the numbers and the clues. Then set the borders for the whole table to 'no borders'.

If you want multiple columns of clues, then add in furter sets of three columns to the right, formatted the same way, with another blank column in between the two sets of three to space them out.

This has the added bonus of making it easy to change the formatting (e.g. font, size, bold) of only the numbers or only the text, as you can select by column and change en masse. Plus you can use the table as a template in the future, and easily adjust the spacing between number and clue by resizing the blank column. If you're so inclined, you could even add a column for the number of letters in the answer.